# Can a Jew name a child after a (deceased) non-Jew (non-relative)?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, names, children-parenting

Can a Jew name a child after a (deceased) non-Jew (non-relative)?  Is there any prohibition against it?

Comment: Related, but **not** duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78/5323 (Matt's [answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43730/5323) there comes highly recommended)

Comment: Consider the name Alexander which came from Alexander the great. Mordechai came from Marduk. Esther was a Hebraization of Ishtar. certain secular names were originally derived from Hebrew but people have forgotten that

Comment: @sabbahillel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41220/5323

Comment: @sabbahillel - Such as "Toby" which is derived from "Tuvia."

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no formalized halachic restriction on how to name a child. One commonality is not to name a child after a Jewish enemy, but I know of no halacha against doing so. (It would be weird to find a Jewish boy named Nebuchadnezzar :-) Besides it being a "nasty" name, it's too long. And, you wouldn't want to shorten it to "nebbish".)

Consider these examples:

Abram and Sarai were non-Jewish names. Is Yishma'el a "Jewish" name? Yet, we know of a Rabbi Yishma'el who is mentioned many times in the Talmud, as well as our morning davening.

Names such as Dov-Ber, etc. are named after animals. I know a few people having this name who were not named after anyone.

As @sabbahillel indicated, above, Alex(ander) is a popular name. Many German Jews named their sons Franz after Franz Joseph.

Comment: I've heard of a Nimrod. Not quite Nebuchadnezzar, but...

Comment: Antignos of Socho?

Comment: @JohnDonn - It's a Greek name, as was common at the time. There were many converts, as well. What point are you making?

Comment: @DanF just wanted to add an example - when I read Pirkei Avot, it came as a surprise to me to find among the highest Torah she-be-`al peh authorities a Greek name as well.