# Halachot of Naming (kids)

Tags: halacha, names, children-parenting

Has naming children ever formed systematized Halachot?

Or is it left as a sort of a prophecy to the parents?

Comment: There are definitely rules, and above all, customs. Naming children after deceased relatives, not naming them after the living, alternating choice of name between husband and wife, etc.

Comment: @sah which of those is not just a custom

Comment: @DoubleAA None, afaik. He didn't exactly exclude customs in his question...

Comment: @SAH Care then to mention which are "definitely rules"?

Comment: related on MY: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45248/can-a-jew-name-a-child-after-a-deceased-non-jew-non-relative and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-it-permissible-to-name-ones-child-with-a-name-from-the-opposite-gender

Comment: relevant sources: http://download.yutorah.org/2009/1109/735718.pdf, https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/1418506/baby-names-halacha-rabbi-yair-hoffman.html, https://www.bvkkosher.com/naming---halacha-and-hashkafa, https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1158837/jewish/The-Laws-of-Jewish-Names.htm, https://halachablog.com/2016/09/09/naming-a-child-after-someone-who-was-not-observant/