# Are there any limitations on changing a personal name in Halachah?

Tags: halacha, names

Following ["naming-a-child-an-embarrassing-name"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97436/naming-a-child-an-embarassing-name/), I stated, based on my personal understanding, that there are no Halachic limitations on how a person calls himself and how he can change his names through his life.

Are there any Halachic limitations on the following:

- **Is a child allowed to be called a name different from what his parents gave him?** For example, the kids's given name is Alex, but in his Heider he wants to be called Avrohom. If yes, from what age or in which circumstances?
- Is there a limitation on how many names a child can be called in the same or different environments?