# Choosing name for our children

Tags: product-recommendation, names, children-parenting

Is there a comprehensive list which we can pick names from? I’m looking for all traditional names, not names that are modern creations or not Jewish originally.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why didn't you flag this question? It's not about Judaism AND it asks for a list, both off this site's scope.

Comment: @AlBerko Where do you get that comprehensive lists are out of scope? Just because it’s a list doesn’t mean it’s too broad.

Comment: Alexander wasn't originally a Jewish name

Comment: I'm voting for closed but cause "Jewish names" historically shift based on location, culture, etc and therefore there is no real religious aspect to Jewish names. This isn't about Judaism so it's off topic.

Answer (score 5):

Considering your criteria, I'm assuming you would appreciate this seffer: [שמות בארץ](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/36150483/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5---%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%95-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90)

It's everything Reb Chaim Kanievsky has to say about names, which to use and which not to use.

As found there, even according to Rabbi Kanievsky, it's fine to use names that weren't traditionally Jewish if there was a gadol who had that name already or if someone in a medrash had that name.

In fact he writes there that he thinks he remembers a Medrash Teiman that listed someone with the name Chaim.
(Yes I was looking to see what he had to say about the nontraditional name Chaim. What can I say. I'm that guy.)

Comment: Re. untraditionally Jewish names... His opinion (if you’re citing correctly, I haven’t read the book) is most probably based on the R”I ([Tos. Shab. 12b s.v. שבנא](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Shabbat.12b.1?lang=bi)) who opines that even a name once held by a wicked person can be given if there were other [righteous] people bearing the same name. (Others follow suit but I think R”I is the basis for it.)

Comment: That is quite possible. I don't recall offhand if he mentioned any source for his opinion. If I make it back to the shul I saw the seffer in, maybe I'll try to check.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple lists are available online. They don't make the exact same distinction as you but provide background information for each name that should allow you to decide which is appropriate.

See e.g.,

- chabad for [boys](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3825225/jewish/Popular-Jewish-Hebrew-Boy-Names.htm)
- chabad for [girls](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3847875/jewish/Popular-Jewish-Hebrew-Girl-Names.htm)
- aish for [boys](http://www.aish.com/jl/l/b/48967016.html)
- aish for [girls](http://www.aish.com/jl/l/b/48966261.html)
- [behindthename](https://www.behindthename.com/names/usage/jewish)

We also used and liked the print book [Best Baby Names for Jewish Children](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824604067).

Last, if helpful, I listed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95394/halachot-of-naming-kids#comment314872_95394) a number of sources on *halachot* of baby names.